# Hide item count and pagination from category page in Magento2

Tags: magento2, pagination, items

Is it possible to hide pagination and item count from Magento 2? Preferably only for specific category but if not possible then for all categories...

............

[image]

Comment: did solution worked for you ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is one way to hide limiter and count from listing Page**, there can be others as well

Update your extended **toolbar.phtml** file and Find it at your extended theme path or if not then copy from vendor

```
app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml
```

To hide limiter and count from listing Page comment these lines of code

( added // before "include", this is how we comment php code)

```
<?php //include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml')) ?>

<?php //include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/amount.phtml')) ?>
```

**Keep cache disabled** and run following commands if needed

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Tested and it works, should help you out as well

Comment: Worked without me running the php commands. Thanks for the commenting out tip, so much better than deleting code.

Comment: good, most of the time...these things works without commands , in case if not working then we can try after running commands